# Shariah Law for the disbeliever

Tags: sharia, allah, non-muslim, kufr

A friend once asked me if it would be better for the Non-muslims who don't convert to Islam rather than live under Islamic law. And I said that I didn't know if our laws are better for the non muslims or their own laws are better for themselves as it occurred to me that their own laws would give them religious freedom but ours would not. Is this a statement of kufr by saying that the laws of Allah are not the best?

Comment: Why would you want Shariah and be a non-Muslim? Shariah is law for  everyone and the rules are based on the Quran and Ahadith. The kaafirs do not follow the law of Allah. Allah has made these rules for the better of mankind and these kaafirs don't follow it. Islam does not force everyone to be Muslim. It is for them to decide. Saying that Allah's laws are not the best is directly insulting Allah and an act of Kufr.

Answer (score -1):

There is always a possibility of this sort of happenchance. Although, in general, the Sharia'a is meant for Muslims but its clauses dealing with the non-Muslims would apply to govern their affairs. Practicing their religion freely is one such Sharia'a provision. Guaranteeing the Safety and protection to their lives and properties is yet another such Sharia'a provision. Those who are interested in knowing more about Sharia'a may access:-
    https://shakir2.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/disjunctive-sequel-2/

Thanks

Comment: "Practicing their religion freely is one such Sharia'a provision." This is not true; proselytization of kufr or shirk among Muslims is haram, and many scholars have even restricted things like publicly saying anything in Islam is inferior to another religion.